# How to append a service uuid to the location, which we get from the response of a successful Post request. I am using webClient for the request

Tags: java, api, spring-webclient

I am sending a post request, with a json body, using webclient to the mock simulator(server) which has been created, which gives us the response.
For the post request specifically, I just need the service uuid which is present in the simulator to be appended to the location which I will be retreiving in the client layer.

Comment: Kindly help me on this. It is really urgent

Comment: Can you post your code example